# Overdamped Approximation

Tags: continuum-mechanics, soft-matter

I am reading the paper [*Information transfer and behavioural inertia in starling flocks*](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys3035) (Attanasi et al, 2014) in the field of active matter for an undergraduate course I am taking.
The paper describes the information transfer inside a collective motion of a starling flock.

> "If the overdamped approximation is done, the conservation law is lost and a purely dissipative equation ... is obtained."

I understand the concept of damping when treating an oscillator but not with the equation of motion they have developed from their Hamiltonian which is supposed to be purely dissipative:

$$\frac{\delta\varphi}{\delta t}=-\frac{\delta H}{\delta\varphi}=a^2J\nabla^2\varphi$$

where $\varphi$ is the phase or orientation of the individual in the system, $J$ is the alignment strength and $a$ is the average nearest neighbor distance.

I would be grateful if someone can explain to me what is the "overdamped approximation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR they are using the term "overdamped" to draw the analogy with the equations that one might write for a simple harmonic oscillator, and also to describe the kinds of solutions that these partial differential equations give.

In this paper the authors are discussing equations of motion for the angle $\varphi(\vec{x},t)$ at which birds are flying, in a flock. The equations are presented, and justified, in terms that are familiar to physicists, even though the details of the phenomenon are complex. The "conventional" description is the equation that you have in your question
$$
\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t} = -\frac{\delta H}{\delta\varphi}
= a^2 J \nabla^2 \varphi ,
$$
except that we need to take care with the notation. $\partial\varphi/\partial t$ is the usual partial derivative. $\vec{\nabla}\varphi$ is the spatial gradient $(\partial\varphi/\partial x,\partial\varphi/\partial y)$ in 2D, and $\nabla^2$ is the Laplacian. The term $\delta H/\delta\varphi$ is a *functional derivative* as used in the [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations). The "hamiltonian" is given in the paper, as a spatial integral involving the square of the gradient, $|\vec{\nabla}\varphi|^2$. This is a very common expression seen in the calculus of variations, and one often wishes to discuss the static problem of finding the function $\varphi(x)$ which minimizes $H$ ("equilibrium"). This is where the functional derivative is zero, $\delta H/\delta\varphi=0$. However, it also leads naturally to a dynamical model, in which the derivative $-\delta H/\delta\varphi$ can be treated as a driving force, pushing the system towards equilibrium. That is the basis of the equation above. Again, it is quite common to propose equations of this kind, for instance in soft condensed matter physics (often based on Landau free energies).

It is analogous to writing an equation for the simple harmonic oscillator like this:
$$
\frac{d X}{dt} = -\frac{dV}{dX} = -KX = F(X)
$$
where the potential is $V(X)=\frac{1}{2}KX^2$ and $F(X)=-KX$ is the force. This is not Newtonian or Hamiltonian mechanics: it is the mechanics of Aristotle, where the velocity is proportional to the force. 
It can be derived from Hamiltonian mechanics by adding frictional damping to a harmonic oscillator, and considering the overdamped regime. That is, we write
$$
\frac{dX}{dt} = \frac{P}{M},\qquad \frac{dP}{dt} = F(X)-\zeta P
$$
and take the overdamped limit, so that $dP/dt=0$, hence $P=F(X)/\zeta$,
giving
$$
\frac{dX}{dt} = \frac{F(X)}{M\zeta} .
$$
The constants $M\zeta$ can be combined into the expression for $F(X)$.
These equations give overdamped dynamics: no oscillations. By the same token, the partial differential equation above for $\varphi$ is overdamped. It is recognizable as the diffusion equation, and we should not expect oscillatory behaviour. $H$ is not really a hamiltonian: the equations do not have hamiltonian form.

The authors of the paper are advocating a different dynamics. They propose to introduce a spin variable $s_z$, like a momentum, and their hamiltonian includes an extra term  $s_z(\vec{x},t)^2/2\chi$ where $\chi$ is an inertia. They now derive their equations of motion
$$
\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t} = \frac{\delta H}{\delta s_z}
= \frac{s_z}{\chi}, \qquad
\frac{\partial s_z}{\partial t} = -\frac{\delta H}{\delta \varphi}= a^2 J \nabla^2 \varphi ,
$$
or, combining the two
$$
\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial t^2} = \frac{a^2 J}{\chi} \nabla^2 \varphi .
$$
They make the point that this is Hamiltonian in the new variables,
and that the new equation leads to propagating (oscillatory) modes,
like sound waves,
not to purely damped solutions.
In terms of the harmonic oscillator, the analogous equations are
$$
\frac{d X}{dt} = \frac{P}{M}, \qquad \frac{d P}{dt}=-\frac{dV}{dX} = -KX = F(X)
$$
which, of course, are not damped, are derived from a hamiltonian $H(X,P)$,
and give rise to oscillations.

Just as one could derive the "overdamped" harmonic oscillator equation from these equations, by assuming that the momentum is rapidly relaxed by a frictional term, so I imagine one could derive the "conventional" partial differential equation for $\varphi(\vec{x},t)$ from the hamiltonian ones, by assuming that the spin field $s_z(\vec{x},t)$ is overdamped by frictional effects.